# Floyd's cycle detection for numbers having a repetition in O(n) time and O(1) space

Tags: algorithm

Is it possible to modify Floyd's Cycle Detection Algorithm to find all numbers having a repetition in an array?
I cannot modify the array.

Given an array for size `n` with integers `1,...n-1`, by the pigeonhole principle, there exists a duplicate integer. - *

An implementation of Floyd's cycle detection algorithm successfully helps in finding a duplicate in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

I want to handle the case when there are more than one duplicates. These are my thoughts:

1. Each repetition of a number results in a cycle (assuming the condition *). But no two different integers having a repetition can be in the same cycle. So we have to find all such cycles.
2. Each cycle path would be of the form `--------o` where `---------` is the part where we start the two pointers for our cycle detection algorithm, `o` is the cycle.
3. We have to find entry points of the cycle, so we keep one pointer at the first `-` in our cycle path and the other where the pointers met initially, moving them together at the same speed would result in them meeting at the entry point of the cycle.
4. So if we have the first `-` of our "Cycle path", we can find the duplicate which resulted in that cycle.

How do I find the first `-` optimally for each cycle path? Storing the visited nodes would just result in losing that  O(1) space complexity and it would be relatively better to just use a hashtable instead.

I would need to store some information to tell that the cycle path is already visited so space cannot be `O(1)` as per my understanding, but how do I minimize space in any case.

Is this approach even feasible, am I wrong somewhere in the ideas above? What other method would be feasible utilizing cycle detection and finding multiple duplicates optimally?

Update:
If the approach above is feasible, the problem comes down to exiting the cycle and finding an unvisited cycle. I can find if a cycle is visited by storing the number where our pointers meet initially. So technically taking `O(k)` space for `k` duplicates. Finding another cycle could be done using a randomized start and checking if the cycle is visited or not. But as the number of duplicates found gets closer to `k`, the randomized start would get slower and may never terminate. Also, would there be any smart way to to pick an index for a randomized approach such that it guarantees termination?

Comment: I don't think you have to store the first `-` to run in O(N). Just run a modified version of the algorithm, where each visited node is marked (implementation is up to you) in a way where its original value can be recovered. After running the first iteration,move onto the next node that hasn't been marked run the modified algorithm; remember to map back to the original value for marked nodes in order to determine the neighbors. It'll still run in O(2N) = O(N) time (why?) and clearly uses O(1) space. After reaching the end, unmark all the marked nodes to recover the original array.

Comment: @wLui155 I missed the requirement that the array could not be modified in case you are suggesting that I associate boolean values to every index of the array. So I cannot mark it. Creating another array to store mark/unmark booleans would take extra memory.

Comment: Hmm that makes things a bit tricky - is it that the array is read only to begin with? The method I was thinking about would recover it, but if that's not possible then my proposed approach wouldn't work.

Comment: On the other hand, even if I could modify the array, how will I mark them while preserving the algorithm's further passes within the same cycle path?

Comment: I didn't want to give it away but since the values fall in `[1, n - 1]` you could just negate them, and recovery/calculation would be based on the absolute value.

Comment: Yes, we are assuming that the array is read-only.

Comment: All right, I'm out of ideas then - I think the only way we can guarantee O(N) runtime (because we have to find all duplicates) is to keep track of paths already seen somehow, since we don't want to run the algorithm redundantly. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @wLui155 I don't understand, please elaborate a bit more "assuming, if we can modify the input". I have values from `[1, n-1]` on an array of size `n`, if I visit a node, how do I negate it? Where will I store absolute values to obtain them back? Or are you recommending any bijective function such that output has a `mark` attribute while preserving O(1)? If so, then please give a few hints for such a function.

Comment: To negate a node at index `i` of your array `A` just assign `-A[i]` to `A[i] if A[i] > 0`. The nice thing about negation is that the absolute value function will give the original value (which was guaranteed to be positive). So, you're essentially encoding two states within a single node in constant memory - whether it's visited or not (positive/negative) and the neighbor (the absolute value of the stored value). For example, if we have the input array `[4, 2, 1, 2, 1]` and it's 0-indexed, you'd run the algorithm from index 0 and end up with `[-4, -2, -1, 2, -1]`, where `1` is the duplicate.

Comment: Afterwards, you'd run the algorithm repeatedly on unmarked nodes and find all of them.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't understand the word `negate` as I thought you meant nullify them by maybe making them 0 or taking a compliment, not sure what was I thinking. Thanks for sharing the approach, this makes sense, this is a clever way to `mark` when our input has a non positive or non negative range.

Comment: "each duplicate results in a cycle" -- nope.  You only need one cycle and you can have as many duplicates as you want.  Consider an array full of 1s

Comment: @MattTimmermans That would still make it duplicates of one integer. I think I have not framed the sentence properly, what  I mean is, repetitions of an integer would be represented in a cycle, but no two different integers having a repetition can lie in the same cycle, I have to find all such integers which have a repetition.  I have modified the problem statement now.

Comment: It isn't clear how "each duplicate results in a cycle". If you treat each number as an index in the array, there can be any number of cycles with or without any duplicates. There are 3 cycles in [2,1,4,3,6,5] and no duplicates.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The condition specifies that the maximum number in the array can always be `n-1`, hence 6 cannot be in the array which you have specified.